# stdout too large for a docker container

Tags: docker

So I have a command that produces a huge file and forwards it to another command in a chain through stdout and stdin.
The problem is that this procedure generates a file in /dev corresponding to the stdout which contains the entire file generated from the first command, but this file is too big and hits the memory limit of the container.
I've tried to mount the /dev folder as a volume, but the container does not start, and for other reasons, I would prefer to avoid changing the code so that it writes the output on a file and give the file to the second command.
So does anyone has other ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you update your question to show specifically what you're doing? From  your description, nothing should be creating a file in `/dev`.

Comment: Most of the files in `/dev` are special in some way; for example, reading from `/dev/zero` will produce an infinite stream of null bytes, but they do not actually exist on disk.  If you're writing to `/dev/stdout` or `/dev/fd/1` that goes into the process's normal stdout stream and doesn't actually exist on disk.